# Android: can not find parent view

Tags: android, view, get, parent

My file **layout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

when I try to get parent in activity

```
 EditText edit_name= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
 TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) edit_name.getParent();
```

I got **error**:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: Have you checked my answer below, is it useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set id in TextInputLayout and bind with id and not with getParent().

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to set an id to this TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And

```
EditText edit_name= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
 TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_input_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to add an set an Id to your TextInputLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

After that you can get the TextInputLayout the same way you did get the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want to try the `TextInputLayout` differently.

rather than using :

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) edit_name.getParent();
```

you might want to try :

XML :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="testId"        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Code :

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.testId);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The actual view hierarchy present under TextInputLayout is NOT
>   guaranteed to match the view hierarchy as written in XML. As a result,
>   calls to getParent() on children of the TextInputLayout -- such as an
>   TextInputEditText -- may not return the TextInputLayout itself, but
>   rather an intermediate View. If you need to access a View directly,
>   set an android:id and use findViewById(int).

i.e. to resolve the issue you have to use `findViewById` instead of `getParent`.

Source is [Android official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html):